# Google Map List View InfoWindow help required

Tags: sharepoint-online, google-maps

I have used the guide at the link below to setup a list in SharePoint to pin locations on a Google Map.

http://www.incworx.com/diy-custom-sharepoint-series

I am now trying to implement InfoBoxes so that when you click on the pin it brings up information about the location (pulling info from the list) in a InfoWindow. Then if you want to view additional details you can click on Read More and the list item will open.

Anyone have experience of InfoWindows?

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? "Anyone have experience about x" -> "Yes" probably won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Marker like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coordinates,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: Title
 });
```

Then add an OnClick event with the contents of the InfoWindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
    infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

`marker.content` is where you add a link to a list item

Edit: of course there is more to it than that - e.g. creating a map, adding the marker to a map, etc., but this should help you get started.